# Understanding different sapply output

Tags: r, sapply

Why

```
kappa <- c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.99)

sapply ( kappa, function (t) t)
```

and

```
sapply ( kappa, function (t) print(t))
```

return different results?

thank you!

Comment: Both of those `sapply` calls have syntax errors and don't run. Did you include a comma that you didn't mean to?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you

Comment: They are different because in the second case `print(t)` does two separate things: it prints `t` on the console and returns `t` as the result. The first only returns the result, no printing. So the second case is the same, you're just seeing each item printed along the way before `sapply` finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a comma in your example but you can try this:

```
kappa <- c(0.0001,0.001,0.01,0.1,0.5,0.9,0.99)

sapply (X=kappa, FUN = function (t)t)
```

What is happening in sapply is "Simplify apply" which will simplify ON IT'S OWN BY BASE R - it will try and find the best format to simplify the outcome which in this case is the numbers of kappa as a result of the function

as the outcome is based on the function - function(t) t - this just returns the value of t - which is just kappa

however when you are running a print statement so function(t) print(t) - at each "step" of the apply - it is trying to "simplify" the print call - which is why you get this output one after the other :

```
sapply ( kappa, function (t) t)
```

also as user above commented:

They are different because in the second case print(t) does two separate things: it prints t on the console and returns t as the result. The first only returns the result, no printing. So the second case is the same, you're just seeing each item printed along the way before sapply finishes